# How to do two sorting in r when order matters

Tags: r

I have a data frame consisting of three variables named momentum returns(numeric),volatility (factor) and market states (factor). Volatility and market states both have two -two levels. Volatility have levels named high and low. Market states have level named positive and negative  I want to make a two sorted table. I want mean of momentum returns in every case.

```
library(wakefield)
mom<-rnorm(30)
vol<-r_sample_factor(30,x=c("high","low"))
mar_state<-r_sample_factor(30,x=c("positive","negtive"))
df<-data.frame(mom,vol,mar)
```

[image]

Comment: R-markdown? DOCX or PPTX? HTML? Is this with R-markdown or something else? Can you share sample data? This question is a little weak without sample data.

Comment: @r2evans I have added sample data.

Comment: `r_sample_factor` not found, please make this question reproducible by listing all relevant non-base packages. Also, you did not answer my question: what is the format for your intended output? (I'll add "to the console" in case you just need it in R.)

Comment: @r2evans Sorry for that sir. I have added library

Comment: jeetkamal, I've tried helping, but you aren't answering my question, so I'm going to assume that you want something on the R console. The organization of this looks similar to what `xtabs(mom~vol+mar, data=df)` provides, though you have eight values in the sample table above but no explanation of how you get them. (And the `xtabs` is cross-tabulated data, not columnar like this.) Good luck, I hope that's a good enough start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this with help of data.table package. This approach will do same task in less time.

```
library(data.table)
df<-as.data.table(df)
## if you want results in data frame format
df[,.(mean(mom)),by=.(vol,mar)]
## if you want in simple vector form
df[,mean(mom),by=vol,mar]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is more appropriate apporach

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion given by @r2evans if you want mean of every sorted cases you can apply following code.

```
xtabs(mom~vol+mar,aggregate(mom~vol+mar,data=df,mean))
## If you want simple sum in every case
xtabs(mom~vol+mar,data=df)
```

Comment: Tnx I needed mean in every case

Comment: @jeetkamal please see how to make a reproducible example with r